# TAPI ITAddressDeviceSpecificEven how to get all data from an event?

Tags: python, tapi, pythoncom

I am working with a **TAPI DLL** in Python trying to keep track of all the events that happen.

Faced a problem handling **ITAddressDeviceSpecificEvent** event

```py
<win32com.gen_py.Microsoft TAPI 3.0 Type Library.ITAddressDeviceSpecificEvent instance at 0x274862726400>
```

```py
print(dir(event))
['Address',' CLSID ',' Call ',' _ApplyTypes_ ',' __class__ ',' __delattr__ ',' __dict__ ',' __dir__ ',' __doc__ ',' __eq__ ',' __
format__ ',' __ge__ ',' __getattr__ ',' __getattribute__ ',' __gt__ ',' __hash__ ',' __init__ ',' __init_subclass__ ',' __iter__
',' __le__ ',' __lt__ ',' __module__ ',' __ne__ ',' __new__ ',' __reduce__ ',' __reduce_ex__ ',' __repr__ ',' __setattr__ ',' __s
izeof__ ',' __str__ ',' __subclasshook__ ',' __weakref__ ',' _get_good_object_ ',' _get_good_single_object_ ',' _oleobj_ ',' _p
rop_map_get_ ',' _prop_map_put_ ',' coclass_clsid ',' lParam1 ',' lParam2 ',' lParam3 ']
```

```py
print(event.__ dict__)
{'_oleobj_': <PyIDispatch at 0x0000003FFFC10C90 with obj at 0x0000003FFC9EEE50>}
```

When trying to **access Address, Call and lParam** (
I get an error

**Address**

```py
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352573, 'Member not found.', None, None)
```

**Call**

```py
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147221497), None)
```

And **lParam1**,2,3

```py
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352559, 'Does not support a collection.', None, None)
```

How can data be pulled from this event? With others, the events did not cause problems.

After importing dll to delphi, I looked at the contents of **ITAddressDeviceSpecificEvent**

```pascal
// *********************************************************************//
// Interface: ITAddressDeviceSpecificEvent
// Flags:     (4352) OleAutomation Dispatchable
// GUID:      {3ACB216B-40BD-487A-8672-5CE77BD7E3A3}
// *********************************************************************//
  ITAddressDeviceSpecificEvent = interface(IDispatch)
    ['{3ACB216B-40BD-487A-8672-5CE77BD7E3A3}']
    function Get_Address(out ppAddress: ITAddress): HResult; stdcall;
    function Get_Call(out ppCall: ITCallInfo): HResult; stdcall;
    function Get_lParam1(out pParam1: Integer): HResult; stdcall;
    function Get_lParam2(out pParam2: Integer): HResult; stdcall;
    function Get_lParam3(out pParam3: Integer): HResult; stdcall;
  end;
```

Does anyone have experience with something like this?

UPD:

I found an example in the C language, but unfortunately I don't understand anything in it, can it somehow be converted into python?

```
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE CMyEventNotification::Event(
   TAPI_EVENT TapiEvent,
   IDispatch * pEvent
)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    //...
    switch (TapiEvent) 
    {
        case TE_ADDRESSDEVSPECIFIC:
        {
            ITAddressDeviceSpecificEvent* pITADSEvent = NULL;

            hr = pEvent->QueryInterface( 
                               IID_ITAddressDeviceSpecificEvent,
                               (void **)(&pITADSEvent) );
            // If (hr != S_OK) process the error here...

            // Retrieve data received from the TSP.
            long lParam1=0;
            hr = pITADSEvent->get_lParam1(&lParam1);
            // If (hr != S_OK) process the error here...

            long lParam2=0;
            hr = pITADSEvent->get_lParam2(&lParam2);
            // If (hr != S_OK) process the error here...

            long lParam3=0; 
            hr = pITADSEvent->get_lParam3(&lParam3);
            // If (hr !=S_OK) process the error here...

            // Process the data here.
            // ...
            pITADSEvent->Release();
            break;
        }

        case TE_PHONEDEVSPECIFIC:
        {
            ITPhoneDeviceSpecificEvent* pITPhEvent = NULL;

            hr = pEvent->QueryInterface( 
                            IID_ITPhoneDeviceSpecificEvent,
                            (void **)(&pITPhEvent) );
            // If (hr != S_OK) process the error here...

            // Retrieve data received from the TSP.
            long lParam1=0;
            hr = pITPhEvent->get_lParam1(&lParam1);
            // If (hr != S_OK) process the error here...

            long lParam2=0;
            hr = pITPhEvent->get_lParam2(&lParam2);
            // If (hr != S_OK) process the error here...

            long lParam3=0;
            hr = pITPhEvent->get_lParam3(&lParam3);
            // If (hr != S_OK) process the error here...

            // Process the data here.
            //...
            pITPhEvent->Release();
            break;
        }
        //...
    } // end of switch 
    //...
}
```

Comment: Out Parameters


For example, consider the procedure heading:

`procedure GetInfo(out Info: SomeRecordType);`
When you call GetInfo, you must pass it a variable of type SomeRecordType:

`var MyRecord: SomeRecordType;
   ...
GetInfo(MyRecord);`


Out parameters are frequently used with distributed-object models like COM. In addition, you should use out parameters when you pass an uninitialized variable to a function or procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no solution. pywin32 is not able to parse dll correctly, from which further work with such events is not possible